# What is Pointer-chasing and how it is related to BFS

Tags: algorithm, pointers

While reading a PPT on BFS (Breadth First Searching) I found that BFS can be used where we have " pointer-chasing" . What exactly is a pointer chasing and how is it related to BFS?

Comment: chase pointers. 1. vi. To go through multiple levels of indirection, as in traversing a linked list or graph structure

Comment: [Google, first hit.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/chase-pointers.html)

Comment: This is now the first hit!

Answer (score 9):

Pointers imply a graph on your data. BFS (breadth first search) is an algorithm to search in that graph.

Pointer chasing is just another word for following lots of pointers.

Answer (score 9):

From the hardware perspective (CPU), pointer-chasing is bad for performance because memory reads are in effect serialized in the CPU (ie no ILP). You can't start a read (ie a load instr) until the prior one is done (since the prior load gives us the address for the next load and so on....).

Answer (score 5):

I find it easiest to think of a `Linked List` example.

Lets say we have a `Linked List` with 5 elements.  To get to the 3rd element, you have to use `Pointer-chasing` to traverse through the elements.